# Can't run terminal commands with exec

Tags: javascript, exec, child-process

i'm trying to use exec function in nodejs, but it's not working.

Here is the code that  i'm runing :

```
import { exec } from "child_process";

exec("ssh ubuntu@myserverip", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
    }

    if (stderr) {
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    }

    else {
        console.log(`stdout:\n${stdout}`);
    }
});
```

And that it what it returns :

[image: terminal]

While this is the output if I directly write on terminal :

[image: terminal]

Any idea about how can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you trying to open an interactive session?

Comment: I believe you want to call `spwan` with `stdio` set to `"inherit"`. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use spawn, exec is used to execute commands whose result is going to be delivered to me immediately, or in a very short time, it has to be fast and where the output or the result that is going to be delivered to me is not very large,
because exec creates a Buffer (a memory space) where it will start storing all the output of the command, and besides that it has a timeout, and if the command does not finish in that time it kills the process.